# Blazor, HttpClient & Config.json

Tags: json, blazor, webassembly

I'm just starting out with Blazor (Web Assembly) and linking it to an API.
So this is really a design/code question.

I want to configure a test and production URL (to connect to the API),
Not sure if I'm doing this right/best practice so any examples would be great?
(And I'm pretty sure I'm doing this all wrong!)

I thought I would create a JSON file in the Blazor project and simply have a production and test URL.
I've started this in the program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        private static string ApiConfig { get; set; }

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            LoadJsonConfiguration();

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<INotificationDataService, NotificationDataService>(client =>
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("ApiConfig"));

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }

        public static void LoadJsonConfiguration()
        {
            var config = JObject.Parse(@"/Config/application.json");
            
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"/Config/application.json"))
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
                {
                    var a = reader.Read();
                    ApiConfig = "ReadConfig here??";
                }
        }
    }
```

application.JSON file

```
{
  "Url": {
    "LocalTest": "https://localhost:44302",
    "Production": "https://Todo"
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two `.json` files in the `wwwroot` folder, note the names:

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Url": "https://Todo""  
}
```

`appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
  "Url": "https://localhost:44302"  
}
```

In `Program.cs` :

```
  var url = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Url").Value;
  ...
```

Depending on the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` the relevant url will be loaded.